# Getting output of CLI commands in some text file

Tags: command-line-interface, mininet, topology

I've been trying to simulate various attacks in networks, using mininet-wifi emulator. For some tasks, I need to get the output of mininet-CLI commands into a file, (preferably in text format, but other would work as well). Can anyone guide me on how to achieve the same?

I tried various python commands but I don't know how to implement them in mininet-wifi, CLI.

Comment: You can redirect any CLI output with `>` to a file: `ls > file-list.txt`. Have you tried that? Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: ls > file-list.txt
This method is not working in "Mininet-wifi" CLI.

I have tried searching the mininet-wifi source file, to look for the command whose output is i am trying to get.
I have also tried to create another python file to redirect or copy the output from the console to a desired .txt file, but still i am having troubles to implement this solution in mininet-wifi.

Comment: It always helps to put your attempts in the question, also what Mininet-wifi is outputting and which lines you are trying to get from that.

Answer (score 0):

sudo mn --wifi > op.txt
it has sent only mininet-wifi> cli prompt into op.txt i.e how many times i have given commands and pressed enter those many times mininet-wifi> is repeated no output of the cli command is copied.

mininet-wifi>sta1 ping sta2 > op.txt
this command stored the output of the sta1 ping sta2 till i interrupt the command by pressing ctrl+c

note: prompt never been shown will be shown, just give command